# Cart Codeigniter Session Database Destroyed

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cart

I'm using codeigniter cart in my project and codeigniter version is 3.1.5. The session is always destroyed when i add more than 135 items. When I enter the 136th product, i got this error:

```
Severity: Warning --> session_start(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed C:\xampp\htdocs\ees\system\libraries\Session\Session.php 143
```

Here's is my config file on session:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';

$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'cookie_ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 86400 * 30;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Here is the autoload:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'datatables');
```

How to make codeigniter cart can accept more than 135 items?

Comment: do you have the table created in your database?

Comment: Yes, i created table named "ci_sessions"

Comment: what is data type of column `data` of `ci_sessions` table @Andhika

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, or unless you are not using the recommended blob datatype, you should know that blog only stores 64K of data. Maybe just to test you should change to mediumblob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, the table i created, ci_sessions, only have max 64K of data (blob), So i change into mediumblob and it works fine now